# DocuSign - NO_DOCUMENT_RECEIVED

Tags: c#, docusignapi

When I try to send a document, an error will be generated.
Error calling CreateEnvelope: {"errorCode":"NO_DOCUMENT_RECEIVED","message":"The document element did not contain the encoded document, or there is a problem with the encoding. No documents were found in the request."}

I have already searched the internet but I can't find anything, can anyone help me.

Comment: It would help us if we could see the code you're using to send the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples of how to use Base64 encoding to pass the document bytes to the [eSignature REST API](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/) using the [C# eSignature SDK](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/sdk-tools/csharp/)

https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-csharp/blob/master/launcher-csharp/eSignature/Examples/SigningViaEmail.cs

Here is the relevant C# Code:

```
    // Create document objects, one per document
    Document doc1 = new Document();
    string b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Document1(signerEmail, signerName, ccEmail, ccName));
    doc1.DocumentBase64 = b64;
    doc1.Name = "Order acknowledgement"; // can be different from actual file name
    doc1.FileExtension = "html"; // Source data format. Signed docs are always pdf.
    doc1.DocumentId = "1"; // a label used to reference the doc
```